# How to find a word that starts with a special letter and end with a special letter in SQL, Regular Expression/REGEX

Tags: sql, regex, looker-studio, qregularexpression

I try to learn SQL and Regex at the moment to analyse data in google data studio. I tried to find a solution to my problem but I could not find any online. I have a data source with search queries and I want to tag all queries which are including the company name as "Branded". This Part is easy. I just wrote the following to get it done:

```
case
when REGEXP_MATCH(Query, '.*flnk.*') THEN 'Branded'
ELSE 'Non-branded'
END
```

But now I also want to mark as "Branded" all search queries that contain the company name but are misspelt. So I tried the following:

```
case
when REGEXP_MATCH(Query, '^[f].*[k]$') THEN 'Branded'
ELSE 'Non-branded'
END
```

But with this code, I get a lot of wrong tagged queries, because it tags all strings which start with f and are ending with k. So my question is how can I only tag words as branded which are starting with **f** and ending with **k**?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using

```sql
case
when REGEXP_MATCH(Query, r'.*\bf[a-zA-Z]*k\b.*') THEN 'Branded'
ELSE 'Non-branded'
END
```

The `.*\bf[a-zA-Z]*k\b.*` pattern matches

- `.*` - any text
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `f` - `f` letter
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more letters
- `k` - a `k` letter
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*` - any text

Comment: Thank you! I tried it but I think `\b` does not work in SQL?

Comment: @Yannik Double the backslashes, `'.*\\bf[a-zA-Z]*k\\b.*'` or use `r` prefix, I updated the answer.

Comment: @Yannik Did it finally do what you need? If yes, please consider finalizing the post by voting/clicking on the grey mark on the left.